# Массив объектов Java

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте, во время написния одной программы возник вопрос, которий меня нсторожил.
При создании массива квадратов выбивает ошибку,  в чем дело?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    int n;
    System.out.print("Введіть кількість квадратів: ");
        while (true) {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("Некоректний тип введеного числа! Повторіть спробу: ");
            } else { 
                n = sc.nextInt();
                sc.close();
                return;
            }
        }
  // вс, что здесь пишу unreachable statement      
}
}
```

Comment: unreachble statement

Comment: может замените `retrun` на `break` ?

Comment: А зачем каждый раз создавать новый Scanner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй ключевое слово `break` для досрочного **выход из цикла**, а не `return`, который в свою очередь **завершает выполнение текущего метода**, и все остальное после `return` считается недостижимым кодом **unreachable code**.

Ну и с массивом попробуй так:

```
Quadrate[] quadrates = new Quadrate[n];
for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    quadrates[i] = new Quadrate(..);
```

Comment: так пробовал с самого начала

Comment: @MuscledBoy кинь полный код

Comment: @MuscledBoy обновил ответ

Comment: дело было в break. а почему именно его надо было писать. Ведь break используеться для завершения выполнения  цикла, а return возвращат управление после выполнения метода?

Comment: или это потому, что цикл. так сказать - вечный

Comment: ага понял, спасибо

Comment: @MuscledBoy отлично.